# AngularJS callback error and is not a function

Tags: angularjs, http

I have an error in line `callback(response.data)` telling that **callback is not a function**. Well, I am new to this and I am trying to figure out how to fix this issue but I am having a tough time. Any idea is appreciated. Thanks

```
 app.service('NotificationPollService', function ($q, $http, $timeout) {

      var notification = {};
      notification.poller = function (callback, error) {
          return $http.get('api/sample.php').then(function (response) {
              if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
                  callback(response.data);                 
              } else {
                  error(response.data);
              }
              $timeout(notification.poller, 2000);
          });
      }

      notification.poller();

      return notification;
});
```

Comment: You are not passing any function to `notification.poller();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared `poller` as a function that receives two functions as its parameters, but you are invoking it with no parameters in two different places:

```
    notification.poller();
```

and

```
    $timeout(notification.poller, 2000);
```

Remember you can log the value of the variables to the console as `console.log(callback, error)`, in which case you will see it prints `undefined, undefined`.

What was the intention of invoking `notification.poller()` in that line? Looks like that function should be called by the user of your service instead, like this:

```
    notification.poller(data => console.log(`Received some data! ${data}`),
                        error => console.error(`Some error occurred: ${error}`));
```

Lastly, what is the intention of `poller`? By the name I imagined it was going to invoke that endpoint some fixed X number of times (polling) and after X failures it would give up, but it's always invoking `poller` again, even after a success.

Comment: it will be called to my `controller`. passing `callback` into `notification.poller(callback)` gives an error `callback is undefined`. anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: updated the answer, there are 2 places where that function is invoked with no arguments. Also, you cannot invoke it like you want: `notification.poller(callback)` because it takes 2 parameters.